# Vue: Why aren't list's items responsive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list of items that I pass to the component as props. Then I want to create  a computed list mapped on the props list. What I do:

```
computed: {
    assets: function(){
        var self = this;
        var mappedList = [];
        if (self.sourceList && self.sourceList.length){
            mappedList = _.map(self.sourceList, function(asset){
                return { title: asset.title, id: asset.id};
            });
        }
        return mappedList;
    }
}
```

I can see the mapped list then rendered:

```
<div v-for="asset in assets"  :key="asset.id">
   <span>{{asset.title}}</span>
   <input v-model="source.title" />
</div>
```

I can't figure out why but when I change a title it's not changed for the item is being edited.

(If I try just create a new list and use push method to add items into it, the result is the same).

UPD Solution found. As @WW noted some data should be used. I just move the list to the data and watch props and it worked.

Comment: The data underlying your computed value needs to be declared in a `data` element of the component.  Otherwise Vue can't track changes.  In other words, you can't `sourceList` needs to be declared in the component.  You haven't shown this code.

Comment: @WW.Thanks! I thought the same and it worked!

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked

Comment: @WW. Thanks, will check it!